# Auto select developer team per Xcode scheme

Tags: ios, xcode

I belong to two teams, App Store and Enterprise. I'd like XCode to automatically select the appropriate team such as:

- The `App Store Release` scheme selects the App Store team.
- The `Enterprise Release` scheme selects the Enterprise team.